# How to install Ubuntu with a non bootable disk

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I want to install Ubuntu from a non bootable Ubuntu disk. I currently have Windows XP installed. How can I do that?

My intention is to remove Windows completely.

Comment: Should be moved to superuser

Comment: Why is the Ubuntu disk unbootable? Do you mean that your PC won't boot from the DVD drive?

Answer (score 3):

You'll either need to create a boot disk that can boot into the Ubuntu disk or just create a new bootable Ubuntu disk.  The easiest way is possibly to use a spare USB drive (or even SD/CF/etc. card) with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).  (Ones large enough to fit a CD are practically given away in cereal boxes nowadays.)

Comment: @Peter: I did not mean just USB drives. SD/CF and other cards are practically given away too.

Comment: @Roger Pate: I am sorry. But consider UNetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to boot from an external media of some form: floppy (not so common anymore), CD/DVD, or USB are the most common. An external hardware with a flexible bootloader (i.e. [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/)) would work, but generally harder unless you have physical access to a system already running GNU/Linux (Ubuntu or otherwise).

Assuming this is a reasonably modern standard PC (less than 8-10 years old) it can most likely boot from optical media (CD or DVD), and most newer systems can boot from USB media (flash drive or external harddrive).

The gotcha may simply be that to speed up the boot process, and to prevent from accidentally booting from a disc left in the CD/DVD drive, the boot settings in the BIOS may be disabled or be configured to boot from the primary hard-drive first. If so, you can simply do into the BIOS settings, and change them so you can boot from external media (CD and/or USB). The exact menus and menu item names vary based on BIOS model, but look for **Boot** or **Boot Settings** as most likely menu names. The computer most likely came with a user manual (may be downloaded at manufacturer's website) that gives basic instructions on how to enter the BIOS and make changes if you are not familiar with the process.

As far as I know you cannot use [LOADLIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadlin) ([alt](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Loadlin+Win95-98-ME.html)) or [SysLinux](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/The_Syslinux_Project) from within a 32-bit OS such as Windows XP. (only 16-bit like DOS). SysLinux or ISOLinux are often used on bootable Linux CDs.